# Why are some of the objects saved with duplicates inside? Only the last clicked product is saved as normal object. javascript

Tags: javascript, object, local-storage

I found that my script saves both objects within an object. But doesnt do it on one of the objects. Why is it saving duplication of all the clicked items within the clicked object? I cant continue with my code until I get the clicked items saved in one object each, without any inside duplication. I dont know where in my code I can find the issue. I have debuggd it so far that when it saves into the localStorage from main.js it its in one object each in setItems(). But when the checkout() is runned, the console.log shows duplication of the objects inside some of the objects, not all. Mostly its one object that is showed as it should, without inside duplications. Ill attach the scripts from main.js and cart.js.

main.js

```
  function setItems(product){
    let cartItems = localStorage.getItem('productsInCart')
    cartItems = JSON.parse(cartItems)
    console.log(cartItems) //works
    if(cartItems != null){
        if(cartItems[product.img] == undefined){
            cartItems = {
                ...cartItems,
                [product.img]: product
            }
            console.log(cartItems)
        }
        cartItems[product.img].inCart += 1
        console.log(cartItems) //works
    }else{
        product.inCart = 1
        cartItems = {
            [product.img]: product
    }
    console.log(cartItems)//funkar
  
    }
    
    localStorage.setItem('productsInCart',JSON.stringify(cartItems))
    console.log(localStorage.getItem('productsInCart'))
  }
```

cart.js

```
    //checkout
    function checkout(id){
            let cartItemsObj = localStorage.getItem('productsInCart')
            cartItemsObj = JSON.parse(cartItemsObj)
            console.log(cartItemsObj)
            
            let cartArray = Object.values(cartItemsObj)
            console.log(cartArray )
            let index = ''
            cartArray.map((item) =>{
              index= item.id
              console.log('DATA OBJ ID', index)
            })
```

}

this is how it looks in the console.log
where 1product has duplications from both 1product and 2 product. While 2product is saved normal.

Thanks in advance
[image]